# Slash at the end of the address after posting a comment

Tags: comments

It’s about the old Expressionengine 1.

After submitting the comment form, a URL with a slash at the end is returned. How to get rid of it?

I have seen various methods, but they relate to .htaccess and remove the slash everywhere and I only need in the comment formreturn url.

Thank you!

Comment: Just tell me how the form field is formed `<input type = "hidden" name = "RET" value = "my_url /">` so that I can remove the closing slash from there. Thanks.

Comment: The only thing I came up with was to add a second <input type = "hidden" name = "RET" value = "full url without slash"> to the template. The form will use it instead of the first one generated by EE. The only problem is that you have to call the additional {exp: weblog: entries} to get the page address. Maybe they can tell me a way to just not generate a closing slash? :)

Comment: welcome to ExpressionEngine StackExchange. Please avoid adding additional information as answers, edit your post instead or add comment (not answer). Also please add appropriate tags for your question.